# 対する vs 関する？　For to 'relate' meaning

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

What is the difference between 対する and 関する？　For the 'relate' meaning.

Comment: They are not confusing at all to me.  Can you post an example sentence/scenario of when you'd have trouble picking the correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two phrase are fundamentally different. I guess you could loosely translate them both as 'related to' but I will list a few examples that hopefully show how different and not interchangeable they are.

**Examples and Differences:**

first - the 対 character is often used in words meaning opposition, or contrast (一対一、対立）while the 関 character is often used in words meaning relation (関係、関連）

～に対して： Is defined as toward (as in an attitude toward), in contrast to, in regard to.

～に関して：Is defined as concerning, with regard to, about, on. Can be used similar to について

Example:

> Americans views regarding Russia... (have become harsh, were incorrect etc.)
>
> アメリカ人のロシアに対しての考え方が....

vs.

> I wrote a report regarding Russia's goverment
>
> 私はロシアの政治に関する論文を書きました。

You can see in these examples that に対して is used to indicate america's views *towards* Russia, while に関する was used as regarding/about.

As shown in the examples below, に対して　cannot be to indicate a pure "about", as in "the class was about space" or "the lecture was about his journey".

> Last week, a meeting was held about Tokyo's tax policy.
>
> 先週、東京の税制に関しての集会が行われた。

You could not use に対して in this sentence.

Lastly, に対して can be used to mean "in contrast" where 関して has no such meaning.

> In contrast to City A, who's economic situation is very stable, City B's economy is crumbling.
>
> A市の経済状態がかなり安定しているのに対して、B市の経済状態は崩れているのだ。